# Different (transformed) JenkinsFile (or any file in fact) based on different environment in .net core and visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I would like to transform a config file (JenkinsFile this time) based on the environment (dev, staging, prod) in .net core app in visual studio 2017.

I do not want to create a different config file for each environment and maintain them all, when they differ only by two first lines.

Ie, I do not want:

- Jenkinsfile.DEV
- ...
- Jenkinsfile.PROD

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In jenkinsfile, for you to segregate environments, you can create a conditional with the "[IF](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax)" sentence.
**Example :**

```
node {
    stage('Example') {
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
        } else {
            echo 'I execute elsewhere'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to do it without branching. right now I am using env.JOB_BASE_NAME which is not great... but works